# Using jQuery to realize a click event for a span without using ID and Name

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

How to use jQuery to click the span tab like below?

like this:

```html
<span data-bind="event: {click: toggleshow}, css: {open: more()}" class="">
    Expand<span></span>Search</span>
```

Comment: <span data-bind="event: {click: toggleshow}, css: {open: more()}" class="">
        <!-- ko text: more() ? "Close" : "Expand" -->Expand<!-- /ko --><span></span>Search</span>

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you just trying to fire a click event?

Comment: Hi Jacques, Yes, I just want to realize the click event on this span

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a css class to your span and use the css class as your jQuery selector for registring the `click` event

```
<span class="myspan" id="someId">Test</span>
<span class="myspan" id="someOtherId">Test Again</span>
```

And the jQuery code will be

```
$(function(){

   $("span.myspan").click(function(e){
     alert("clicked");
     var itemId=$(this).attr("id");
     alert(itemId);
   });

});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/wamuma/edit?html,js,output) is a working sample

If you cannot add a css class or other attributes to this span, you might need to use a very wide jQuery selector, which is just the `span` tag.

```
$("span").click(function(e){
  alert("clicked");
});
```

But this click event will be registered to **all span's** in your page. Another option is to wrap these spans inside a container div and use that in your jQuery selector so that only those span's will be registered for the click event.

```
<div id="myContainer">
   <span data-bind="event: {click: toggleshow}, css: {open: more()}" class="">
                                                          Expand<span></span>Search</span>
</div>
```

And the jQuery code to register the click event will be

```
$(function(){

     $("#myContainer span").click(function(e){
     alert("clicked");

   });

});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/boxori/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample of that.

Comment: Thx Shyju, I cant add any class name or id, because I'm trying to learn how to use Jquery to handle any situation. This is my target.

Comment: Id is not necessary. I just added that to so that i can alert than on the click in the example. Only css class is needed

Comment: The CSS class is null, I cant find it in developer tools (F12) in Chorme

Comment: what you mean, It is null. You need to add the css class to your markup. See the sample i posted in the answer.

Comment: I know there should be a value for CSS class, but the tricky thing is there is not. I show you the whole span element:  <span data-bind="event: {click: toggleshow}, css: {open: more()}" class=""> Expand<span></span>Search</span>

Comment: You can see, there is no value for the css class

Comment: Can't you add a css class to the span ?

Comment: No, I can't. I just don't know how to get the span element. I know how to use ID and Class value, but this is the tricky one I have never meet

Comment: Thank you sooooo much, I will look up and find some div or other elements that the span has been included

Comment: Thank bro, its working now. I do appreciate your help. Thx

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can take pretty much any CSS selector.

So if you don't want to use a class or an id (which you should), there are 2 options:

1. [Read up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) about CSS selectors and find an appropriate one.
2. Open
   the inspector tools in your browser, right click on your span
   element in the HTML view and choose the option *"Copy Unique
   Selector"* (Firefox) or *"Copy > Copy selector"* (Chrome) to get an
   automatically generated selector for your element.

Then use it normally with jQuery: `$("copy_pasted_probably_very_long_selector").click()`

Comment: So, you mean I just need to copy the element and past into the jQuery? Thx, I will try it now

Comment: The string you get should look something like that: `#comment-56785674 > td:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)`

Answer (score 0):

**1st:** in html use

```
</span><span>Search</span>
```

instead of

```
 <span></span>Search</span>
```

**2nd:** while you tagged javascript/Jquery for click event so you can use `.filter()`

```
$('span').filter(function(){
   return $(this).text().trim() == 'Expand';
}).on('click' , function(){
      //code here for Expand span
});
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/vvfu27nb/) This will work with Expand span .. use the same way for Search one

Comment: I just need to realize the click event, so can I rewrite your code like this?       $('span').filter(function(){
   return $(this).text().trim() == 'Expand';
}).click();

Comment: @TaotaoFeng updated answer with demo .. click the Expand span there

Comment: @TaotaoFeng yes you can use .click() as well .. but I used to use .on() to work in many cases else

Comment: Actually, there are two spans                                                                    <span data-bind="event: {click: toggleshow}, css: {open: more()}" class="">                                                                                                              <!-- ko text: more() ? "Close" : "Expand" -->Expand<!-- /ko -->                   <span>                                                                                  </span>                         Search                                                                                                     </span>

Comment: Sorry, I still can't realize the click function, This is not my html, I just found one from online, I just want to practice my jQuery skill

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `event` object to find the `nodeType` .Here is a snippet to illustrate it

HTML

```
<span class="item-content">Button 1 </span>
<span class="item-content">Button 2 </span>
<div class="item-content">Button 3 </div>
<button class="item-content">Button 4 </button>
```

JS

```
$('body').on('click',function(event){
alert(event.target.nodeName)
})
```

event object have many other keys which can also come handy when required.You can just `console.log(event)` so see others keys.

[WORKING MODEL](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/vhb726qg/5/)

**NOTE:** I used multiple tags just for demonstration. Also though each element have a class but I used it just for styling.

Hope this will be useful